# Django rest transform flat data to relational data in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a setup where I need to write an API for an existing javascript datamodels which i do not want to touch (for now). The javascript data has a different architecture than I want to have on the server. So my goal is to transform the data that I get from javascript to fit my database model when data is sent to the API. When data is requested from the API, it should match the expected data model of javascript.

I wonder if I can do that with ModelSerializers, if yes, where is the right place to transform the data? In the view? In the serializer.

My setup is like so:

```
//javascript structure
{
  scores: [
    {
      id: 12,
      points: 2
      maxpoints: 12
      siteuxid: 'EXAMPLE'
    },
    { ... }
  ]
}

//More models in django
{
  scores: [
    {
      id: 12,
      points: 2,
      question: {
        id: 12,
        maxpoints: 12,
        siteuxid: 'EXAMPLE'
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Are there any examples anyone can point me to, that achive the same? Basically it is all about having different data structures in server and client and making them compatible. Googleing did not help.

**EDIT:**
My first problem is that I do not get all posted data in my Serializer. When I post

```
{
    "scores": [{"id":"QFELD_1.1.3.QF2","siteuxid":"VBKM01_VariablenTerme","section":1,"maxpoints":4,"intest":false,"uxid":"ER2","points":0,"value":0,"rawinput":"363"}]
}
```

to

```
class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    scores = ScoreSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('userDataSerializer validated_data', validated_data)
        ...

class ScoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    question = QuestionSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = ('id', 'question', 'points', 'value', 'rawinput', 'state')
```

I only get the output

```
userDataSerializer validated_data {'scores': [OrderedDict([('id', 'QFELD_1.1.3.QF2'), ('points', 0), ('value', 0), ('rawinput', '363')])]}
```

without the `score.maxpoints` and so on (as it is not in the serializer, but how can I add it? To validated data in order to create a proper question object from the posted data in UserDataSerializer)

Comment: This would normally go into the serializer and the DRF documentation should at least get you started. Unless there is non-trivial business logic - in that case, you might want to create an adapter or maybe proxy models that are serialized by ModelSerializer and have a way to save/update their corresponding regular model. You would have to provide more detail on the business logic though if you want help on that.

Comment: Updated to show you more of my code

Comment: The serializer will of course only return the values for the fields specified in `Meta`. Add the missing fields to `Meta.fields` and add the necessary methods to validate and transform the fields in the serializer - or do it in the view, if you prefer that. Though if you only support that format then this is what your serializer should be doing - that is the abstraction layer between the incoming data and your internal data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you will use the view to modify your input data, as you must do these tweaks in your data before the view sends the data to the serializers. This is due to the same reason that you only see the attributes of your serializer in your validated data - the serializer ignores all the attributes it does not recognize.

So, first of all, change `request.data` in your view's `post` method to make it structured as you need.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.data['question'] = {
        'maxpoints': request.data.pop('maxpoints'),
        'siteuxid': request.data.pop('siteuxid'),
    }
```

This should be all you need to get started.

However, note that it's strange that `question` has `id: 12` in your example. If you are trying to create a `question` object along with your `score` object, it should have no `id`. If the question is an existing object, though, you should not be sending a dict, but only the `id` instead.

For example, you should send `question: 1` in your input. DRF's `ModelSerializer` is smart enough to know that the `score` you are trying to save is to be related with the `question` which has `id = 1`. While you're at it, inspect the serializer's `validated_data` and you'll see the instance of `question` with `id = 1`. Magic!